# Appended ToolbarHandler mapper action not called on iOS

Tags: ios, maui, handler

I want to customize the toolbar in Android and iOS. For this purpose I tossed my old renderers and appended a mapper for the ToolbarHandler:

In Android the code is reached and executed (in Platforms.Android.MainApplicatinon.cs):

```cs
[Application]
public class MainApplication : MauiApplication
{
    public MainApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership ownership)
        : base(handle, ownership)
    {
    }

    protected override MauiApp CreateMauiApp() {

        ToolbarHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("CustomToolbarMapper", (handler, toolbar) =>
        {
            var materialToolbar = handler.PlatformView;
            materialToolbar.ContentInsetStartWithNavigation = 0;
            materialToolbar.TitleCentered = true;
        });

        return MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp();
    }
}
```

On iOS the appended mapper action doesn't get triggered at all (in Platforms.iOS.AppDelegate.cs):

```cs
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public class AppDelegate : MauiUIApplicationDelegate
{
    protected override MauiApp CreateMauiApp() {

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("IN CREATE MAUI APP iOS");

        ToolbarHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("CustomToolbarMapper2", (handler, toolbar) =>
        {
            // Not reached!!
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("IN TOOLBAR HANDLER");
        });

        return MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp();
    }
}
```

Steps to Reproduce
Append a custom mapping to the existing ToolbarHandler.Mapper property.
Run the project on iOS.
Expected result:
The code in the appended mapper action is called.

Current result:
The code in the appended mapper action is not called.

Link to public reproduction project repository
https://github.com/JordiCasas/ToolbarHandlerIssue

Here there's a screenshot proving that the reproduction repo works on Android (note that the title is centered):

[image]

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thanks for the suggestion. As you can see in the edited question, the code that demonstrates the broken behavior is in the AppDelegate.cs. I also tried to have the code in MauiProgram.cs with conditional compile directives but the result is the same.

Comment: @jordicasas You said In Android the code is reached and executed, does the ToolbarHandler work and take effect?

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT Yes, on Android the code in the handler executes and takes effect properly. The issue is only on iOS.

Comment: @jordicasas thanks for the response, you can see my answer below.

Comment: BTW, the repo you link doesn't have the customization code in Android / MainApplication.cs. I'll assume what you show in question was added later.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve You are right, I forgot to push the changes. Check now please, should be there.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your issue on my side. The issue is that the `ToolbarHandler` listed below not called on iOS, however, it can be called on Android and Windows.

```
ToolbarHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("CustomToolbarMapper", (handler, toolbar) =>
 {
       // Not reached!!
       System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("IN TOOLBAR HANDLER");
 });
```

As an alternative workaround, you can try to use the [Using Custom Renderers in .NET MAUI](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Using-Custom-Renderers-in-.NET-MAUI) to achieve it on iOS.

And I notice that you open a new issue: [Appended ToolbarHandler mapper action not called on iOS #16467](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/16467), you can follow up there.

Thanks for your feedback and patience!

Comment: I see, but does the handler really deal only with ToolbarItems? I don't think so. And in Android it works ok. I suspect this is not the true origin of the issue.

Comment: @Alexandar, a [Toolbar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.toolbar) is not a [ToolbarItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.toolbaritem). The explanation/remark is not accurate/relevant. Also **"it failed"** is not a useful description. Was the code not executed? Did it execute, but do nothing? Or cause an exception? Did you test on both iOS and Android? Did we learn anything from this that is different than what jordi already reported in the question?

Comment: @jordicasas 1.According to [Handler-based views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/#handler-based-views), I don't see ToolbarHandler inside it. 2. Can you help add the screenshot on Android it works ok?I can reproduce the your issue on my side that On iOS the appended mapper action doesn't get triggered at all even within conditional compilation in MauiProgram.cs.

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT 1. How is it that there's a [ToolbarHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.handlers.toolbarhandler?view=net-maui-7.0) and that it works for Android? 2.I will update the question with a screenshot, but you can follow the link for the reproduction repo in my question and deploy it yourself too.

Comment: @jordicasas thanks for the response, you can see my updated answer.

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT So, the only way to achieve what I want is to go back to custom renderers? Alright! Thanks.

Comment: No worries, yes, partially for iOS, for Android and Windows, you can continue using`ToolbarHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping`.